# XamarinForms Exception

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I created a search bar with database connection. When i run it. It get an exception. i use a database that was created before.

Model class entries

```
public class entries
{
    public entries()
    {

    }

    public entries(string word)
    {
        this.word = word;
    }
    public entries(string word, string wordtype, string definition)
    {
        this.word = word;
        this.wordtype = wordtype;
        this.definition = definition;
    }   
    public string word
    { get; set; }

    public string wordtype
    { get; set; }

    public string definition
    { get; set; }

    public List<string> GetWord { get; set; }
}
```

Class DatabaseManager:

```
public class DatabaseManager
{
    SQLiteConnection dbConnection;
    public DatabaseManager()
    {
        dbConnection = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
    }



    public List<string> GetWord()
    {
        return dbConnection.Query<string>("Select word From [entries]").ToList();
    }


}
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
    DatabaseManager dbManager = new DatabaseManager();
 private void MySearchBar_SearchButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void MySearchBar_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var keyword = MySearchBar.Text;
            if(keyword.Length >= 1) { 
                var suggestions = dbManager.GetWord().Where(c => c.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()));

                SuggestionListView.ItemsSource = suggestions;
                SuggestionListView.IsVisible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                SuggestionListView.IsVisible = false;
            }
        }
```

This is Exception:

> System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'System.String' not
>   found.

Please Help. Thank you so much.

Comment: 'I'm new in ...' usually means 'I'm too lazy to use google'. Please do not start your posts like this.

Comment: which specific line throws the exception?

Comment: Thanks Jason!! This is the line that throws the exception:
return dbConnection.Query<string>("Select word From [entries]").ToList();

Comment: @TanVuBoyGib You would need to provide a class that has just one string property and then you can use Linq projection to transform those query results into a string list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have created an Entity for the “entries” table, say for example it is,

```
[Table (“entries”)]
public class Entries
{
    …

    [Column (“word”)]
    public string Word;

    …
}
```

then change the line

```
dbConnection.Query<string>("Select word From [entries]").ToList();
```

to

```
dbConnection.Table<Entries>().Select(x => x.Word).ToList();
```

This will remove the requirement of creating one additional class as Sushi said in above comment.

Moreover, following line will throw a `NullReferenceException` at `c.ToLower()`, if any of the word contains `Null` into the table.

```
dbManager.GetWord().Where(c => c.ToLower().Contains(keyword.ToLower()));
```

So to get rid of this, select results which has not null values like,

```
dbConnection.Table<Entries>().Where(x => x.Word != null).Select(x => x.Word).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys. best wishes to you, @MilanG. Thank you so much. this really works for me.